# org bable use tangle and export to a specified file

Tags: emacs

I tried to export the src code in org babel src to a file

```
#+name: src_file
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results none :tangle ~/test-tangle :exports both
echo "very strang and long string"
#+END_SRC
```

Test it

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results output
cat ~/test-tangle.sh
#+END_SRC
```

but get error

```
 cat: ~/test-tangle.sh: No such file or directory
```

Then changed tangle to yes

```
#+name: src_file_2
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results noe :tangle yes  :exports both
echo "very strang and long string"
#+END_SRC
```

After C-c C-c, search the home dir for "very strange and long string", but just get the current org file.

Where is the src code  export to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tangle the file with <kbd>C-c C-v t</kbd> (`M-x org-babel-tangle`). By the way, be aware that tangle will overwrite your existing file (with the same name) without warning.